# Как связать два поля одной таблицы?

Tags: php, yii2

Все привет!
У меня есть таблица сообщений(messages) со следующими полями:
id, parent_message, message. 
Где parent_message - это указатель на сообщение на которое ответил пользователь, т.е. родителем для сообщение является сообщение из этой же таблицы. У самого первого сообщение родителя нет, ему присваевается null.
Пример сообщений:

```
1 | NULL | 'Привет! Как дела?'
2 | 1    | 'Хорошо'
3 | 2    | 'Чем занимаешся'
4 | 3    | 'Работаю'
```

Теперь я хочу указать связь между этими двумя полями через метод hasOne:

```
class Message
{
    ...

    public function getParentMessage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Message::className(), ['id' => 'parent_message']);
    }
}
```

Связь вроде прописанна правильно, но почему то не работает, метод возвращает какой-то массив чисел(я так и не понял что это).
Скажите так вообще можно делать(связывать два поля одним одной таблицы) этим методом, или в yii2 используется другой способ?
В доках по этому поводу ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Связь прописана корректно.

Метод `getParentMessage()` возвращает экземпляр класса [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) (т. е. запрос к БД).

Чтобы получить само сообщение, вам нужно выполнить выборку по этому запросу:

```
$parentMessage = $message->getParentMessage()->one();
```

Или просто обратиться как к свойству ([магия yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-relational-data)):

```
$parentMessage = $message->parentMessage;
```